# PostgreSQL: How to get weekly average data for each term

Tags: postgresql

I want to get weekly average data for each term.
How could I get them?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkhKU.png)

Comment: What columns you want average for you have five columns in the image?

Comment: The db has daily data with 5 main values(open, high, low, close, volume). I want to get weekly data to average these five values for each term at once. Make sense?

Comment: what query you tried so far, where you got stuck?

Comment: Well, no idea for this. I'm thinking to perform this using the function like date_trunc(), but I don't know where to start this. I hope you guide from scratch.

Comment: You can use a window function to partition your data in 7-days week periods and then apply AVG over each of these partitions.

Comment: @IVOGELOV Can you share the complete SQL for me?

Answer (score 0):

try this query
i used date_part() for extracting currentweekofthemonth,year,month,weekoftheyear

```
SELECT   term,((date_part('day', time::date)::integer - 1) / 7) +1 as currentweekofthemonth, 
 date_part('year', time::date)  AS yr, 
date_part('month', time::date)  AS mon,
date_part('week', time::date) AS weekoftheyear,
round(AVG(open),5)
FROM        yourtablename
GROUP BY    term,currentweekofthemonth, ,yr,mon,weekoftheyear
ORDER BY term,yr,mon,currentweekofthemonth
```

add the other columns you need